# my dynamic data not share in fb using angular

Tags: angular, meta, socialshare, fbsdksharedialog

i have tried to share my post page data to fb, and my post page data change on product wise, its come from server and after that i want to share this data on fb, but i cant get this data on fb share page.

i tried below concept for share data on fb

```
1)ngx-social-button
2)
        let url =  "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/share?app_id=xxxxxxxxx&amp;href="+location.href+"&amp;picture="+this.product.productImageUrl;
        let newwindow=window.open(url,'name','height=500,width=520,top=200,left=300,resizable');
        if (window.focus) {
            newwindow.focus()
        }
```

and update meta dynamic when post data come

```
    this.metaService.updateTag({property: 'og:title', content: product.productName});
    this.metaService.updateTag({property: 'og:type', content: 'website'});
    this.metaService.updateTag({property: 'og:image', content: product.productImageUrl});
    this.metaService.updateTag({property: 'og:image:alt', content: product.productName});
    this.metaService.updateTag({property: 'og:description', content: product.productDescription});
    this.metaService.updateTag({property: 'og:url', content: location.href});
    this.metaService.updateTag({property: 'og:image:height', content:'250px'});
    this.metaService.updateTag({property: 'og:image:width', content:'250px'});
```

but i cant resolve issue for share dynamic data on fb

Comment: You cannot share, FB won't allow to share the data programatically IMO, you can only share link of your application not written text.

Comment: but my link have meta tag for fb share data like image,title,description etc @PardeepJain

Comment: Image can also be shareable not description, it is as per FB policy you can't do anything about it.

Comment: for example you can refer to this and try demo - https://murhafsousli.github.io/ngx-sharebuttons/#/share-buttons-component

Comment: i tried above link but error when install  font-awesome in angula @PardeepJain

Comment: you can exclude that part, font-awesome is just for icons, you can customize accordingly.

Comment: below is the error `ERROR in ./node_modules/@ngx-share/button/fesm5/ngx-share-button.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome'`

Comment: install it sepratly

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge you cannot share data/text (prefilled text like twitter tumbler etc) on Facebook, as per Facebook's policy they won't allow to share content.

> https://developers.facebook.com/policy#control

But yes you can share your link/URLs, Images on facebook. How images crawlers crawl of your application, Off course it's depends on your application whether is it server side supported or not because the problem is that Facebook crawler will only see server side rendered HTML, Facebook will not execute client side javascript.

Also if you want to check how you pages share looks like after sharing it on Facebook, you can test it out here

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing

## Update

To pass dynamic SEO data for every webpage specific you can can set it like this -

```
import { Meta, Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';


@Injectable()
export class SEOService {
 constructor(
    private meta: Meta,
    public title: Title
  ) { }

   this.title.setTitle(`Title here`);
   this.meta.updateTag({ name: 'description', content: 'description here' }); 
}
```

For more info please refer documentation -

- https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/Meta

Comment: Hello, are you available?

Comment: @BhargavChudasama yes tell me

Comment: i didnt find out any solution for fb share issue. any way in angular?

Comment: There is no way buddy, it is as per facebook policy, Angular or React doesn't matter.

Comment: but why meta url data not share? my page have content image,title,description etc

Comment: Image and URL can be shareable, not content. Because as per their policy they won't allow to pass content as content/text.

Comment: but my title and image not display on fb share its default title and image of index.html not update meta

Comment: have you added fb/twitter meta card? also try to clear cache here https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing

Comment: yes i put all related meta tag of fb and also try with fb debugger but always display old title and image

Comment: in angular always hit index.html and its default meta use for fb, but i want share meta of my component load and updated meta

Comment: @BhargavChudasama you can set dynamic META and title using service, please check my updated answer.

Comment: yes i use same and meta also updated but fb share page old meta display. this is the issue

Comment: It won't work unless the pages are rendered from the server-side. Angular universal (https://angular.io/guide/universal) can be a solution, the only downside is that the pages should be served from a node js server.